# Replicate records based on category separated by space in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-01-25','2018-02-11','2018-05-27','2018-07-22','2018-11-11'],
               'Category':['string1 string2','string3','string4','string5 string6','string7']})
```

looks like

```
      Category         Date
   0  string1 string2  2018-01-25
   1  string3          2018-02-11
   2  string4          2018-05-27
   3  string5 string6  2018-07-22
   4  string7          2018-11-11
```

and I'd like to replicate all the records based on how much strings I have in Category column.

So the desired output should look like

```
      Category         Date
   0  string1          2018-01-25
   1  string2          2018-01-25
   2  string3          2018-02-11
   3  string4          2018-05-27
   4  string5          2018-07-22
   5  string6          2018-07-22
   6  string7          2018-11-11
```

Is there any simple way how can I achieve desired output?

Comment: You can use `df['Category'] = df['Category'].str.split()` and then use the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, this works!